# Java BoxLayout use full width

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, boxlayout

I am creating a messaging program that has multiple chats. On the side of the chat window there is a JPanel containing a List Array of all the buttons to switch chats.I am having trouble getting all the buttons in the side panel to be the same width, no matter what they contain. But whatever I try doesn't seem to work and I am looking for some help. Please can you explain what the code does and how it can be used so I can learn it for next time. Sorry if the comments aren't the best it's a work in progress as I wait till code works before adding detailed comments otherwise I am constantly changing them. :(

This is what it looks like without any chats:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OQVDI.png]

This is with multiple chats and you can see the width variation

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fwkna.png]

Here is the code that is run when a new user is added:

```
public void newUser() {
    JPanel dialogue = new JPanel();
    dialogue.setLayout(new BoxLayout(dialogue, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

    //Creating/adding dialogue components
    JLabel Enter_ip = new JLabel("Enter the ip address");
    JTextField Get_ip = new JTextField("");
    dialogue.add(Enter_ip);
    dialogue.add(Get_ip);
    dialogue.add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(15));

    JLabel Enter_name = new JLabel("Enter the user's name");
    JTextField Get_name = new JTextField("");
    dialogue.add(Enter_name);
    dialogue.add(Get_name);

    //Creating the dialogue box
    JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, dialogue, "New User", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);

    //Getting data from dialogue box
    String ip = Get_ip.getText();
    String name = Get_name.getText();

    //Try connecting to other user here

    //Adding user message data
    int size = Users_Messages_Data.size();
    Users_Messages_Data.add(new ArrayList());//New user
    Users_Messages_Data.get(size).add(new ArrayList());//Messages
    Users_Messages_Data.get(size).add(new ArrayList());//Details
    Users_Messages_Data.get(size).get(1).add(name);
    Users_Messages_Data.get(size).get(1).add(ip);
    Users_Messages_Data.get(size).get(1).add("port number");

    //adds new UserButton
    int temp = users.size();
    users.add(new JButton(Users_Messages_Data.get(size).get(1).get(0)));
    users.get(temp).addActionListener(this);
    users.get(temp).setSize(new Dimension(500, 500));
    SelectUser.add(users.get(temp), gbc);
    Messaging.revalidate();
    pack();
}
```

and here is the initialisation method:

```
public void MessagingGUI() {

    //Creates JFrame and pane         
    Messaging = new JFrame();
    Container pane = getContentPane();
    JLabel info = new JLabel("29/07/2016      15:36");

    //Creates user chats panel        
    SelectUser = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
    gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc.weightx = 1;
    gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;

    SelectUser.setLayout(new BoxLayout(SelectUser, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    SelectUser.setSize(new Dimension(500, 500));

    //Adds different chats        
    users = new ArrayList<JButton>();
    int x;
    for (x = 0; x < Users_Messages_Data.size(); x++) {
        users.add(new JButton(Users_Messages_Data.get(x).get(1).get(0)));
        users.get(x).addActionListener(this);
        SelectUser.add(users.get(x), gbc);
    }
    JButton newUser = new JButton("+");
    newUser.addActionListener(this);
    SelectUser.add(newUser);
    JScrollPane UserScroll = new JScrollPane(SelectUser,
            JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS,
            JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);

    //Creates messages feed        
    JPanel Messages = new JPanel();
    Messages.setLayout(new BoxLayout(Messages, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    AllMessages = new JTextArea(10, 30);
    AllMessages.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    AllMessages.setEditable(false);
    AllMessages.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLUE, 1));

    JScrollPane MessageScroll = new JScrollPane(AllMessages,
            JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS,
            JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);

   //Creates user text entry box        
    UserText = new JTextArea(5, 30);
    //UserText.setLineWrap(true);
    //UserText.setWrapStyleWord(true);
    UserText.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.CYAN, 1));
    UserText.setText("Enter Message. Press enter to send");
    UserText.setFocusable(true);
    UserText.addKeyListener(this);
    UserText.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(5, 20));

    //Adds all components to pane        
    Messages.add(info);
    Messages.add(MessageScroll);
    Messages.add(UserText);
    pane.add(UserScroll, BorderLayout.WEST);
    pane.add(Messages, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    //JFrame setup        
    Messaging.setTitle("Messaging");
    Messaging.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    Messaging.setContentPane(pane);
    Messaging.setVisible(true);
    Messaging.setSize(400, 350);
    Load_User(current_user);
}
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: I see that you've gotten this [mcve] recommendation before, and that's because it is a very good recommendation. Also, please consider accepting camickr's answer below.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, variable names should NOT start with an upper case character. Some of your variable names are correct, other are not. Be consistent and follow Java conventions!!!

> .I am having trouble getting all the buttons in the side panel to be the same width,

Don't use a BoxLayout. It does not automatically resize on the opposite axis of the layout.

Instead you can use:

1. a `GridLayout` to make all the buttons the same size. The `GridLayout` will also fill the area vertically which is not what you want so you will need to nest panels. So create a parent panel using a `BorderLayout`. Add your panel using the `GridLayout` with the buttons to the `BorderLayout.PAGE_START` of this parent panel. Then add the BorderLayout panel to the scroll pane.
2. a `GridBagLayout`. You will need to use the "fill" contstraint to have the component fill the width of the cell.

Read the Swing tutorial on [Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) for more information and examples.

Or maybe a different approach is to use a `JList` to display the users.

Comment: Wow, I've never thought to use the `BorderLayout.PAGE_START` for this problem before, I'll give it a try later, I've solved this by adding each button to a new JPanel with a FlowLayout each